# Cross Vuser Transactions in Loadrunner

Tags: transactions, loadrunner

I am currently developing loadrunner scripts for performance testing of an application which processes in asynchronous mode. The application, which I am doing performance testing accepts input files through SFTP and send processed output on an output location through SFTP.

In order to build script to measure performance of the application, I am planning to use two Vugen Scripts, one for submitting the input file and the second one for receiving the output file. To measure the time duration between input and output, I wanted to user Cross Vugen Transaction.

I have gone through the documentation in user guide but that is too little for me to understand and implement. Could you please provide me with a sample script or more detailed steps on how to implement, execute and view Cross Vugen Transactions.

Please note that I am beginner in vugen scripts and any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to manually handle how to correlate which starting transaction lines up with which ending transaction. Loadrunner doesn't do this natively.

One way may be to insert transaction ID's and their start date/time into a VTS table in the first script. Then the second script reading from that same table, finding the matching transaction ID then using a lr_user_data_point() to log a custom transaction time.

Alternatively, if there were some way to get start time after the fact, such as reading a 'created' timestamp value in your output file to get the start time - you could then calculate the time difference in your second script and use lr_custom_data_point().

If all else fails it might be easiest to simply save everything to two log files and calculate the time differences manually later on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function, lr_start|end_distributed_transaction() which purports to handle this situation directly.  However, if you do some research on both LoadRunner Yahoo Group and the lr-LoadRunner google group, you will find that this function is inconsistent in its operation.  There are several alternate paths

As Michael Galos noted, you can place information on a broker between scripts, using VTS, RabbitMQ, Amazon Simple Queue Service, a queue table in a traditional database, ..., then the second user can pick up information on the start time (ideally in unix time milliseconds), calculate the difference to current time and then use the lr_set_transaction() function to create a transaction on the fly.   This model does have some issues because it assumes a maximal queue depth on passing from one virtual user to another of 1 with no delay and it assumes that the next item popped off the queue will be the correct item, which is not always true in an asynch model.

You can also use what would be termed marking data in the record you are processing.  For instance, if your record allows numbers to be used instead of a middle name, as an example, consider using the unix timestamp as the middle name.  Then as soon as you pull your record you have a copy of the originating time when placed on the queue earlier.  This also avoids having to integrate an additional infrastructure.    With the start time as a part of the originating record and the end time a part of your local virtual users then you can once again use lr_set_transaction() to create your transaction on the fly.

The optimal situation is a back end database which is tracking the time required for processing the asynch request.  Let's assume that the record, once it arrives, requires multiple stages of processing.  An audit trail which tracks arrival times at various stages can be used to produce a set of datapoints at the end of the test which can then be pulled into Analysis as part of your test reporting.  Not only can this provide optimal processing time, as you will see the time perspective from arrival on one queue to placement on an outbound queue for pickup ( without delays from client processing or network ).   Such audit trails also assist in production debugging when an element is "stuck".   As an alternative you can also process logs where this information may be collected.   I like to use Splunk for this process, but others go for the ELK stack or even Microsoft Logparser.   A query exported to datapoints (database audit trail, Splunk, ELK or LogParser) which are picked up in Analysis does become the most elegant solution for Analysis and presentation.

Here is your weak point in all of this.  Your system clock.  Make sure that all of your system clocks are synchronized across all of your virtual user load generators and hosts that you will be pulling timing data from.  If you are in a virtual machine environment this becomes problematic because the virtual machines will use a virtualized system clock that eventually has to synch to the physical system clock.   This can cause clock jump resulting in what appears to be a longer timing record than in a hardware clock environment.  The net on this is that you will have higher average, maximum, standard deviation and 90th/95th percentile response times.   You can cover this contingency by having a couple of hardware load generators in the loop as control elements and then using the timing records for this set as a control against any skew in your virtualized load generators.   Food for thought.